# Python - Rename function returned by other function

Tags: python, function, types, functional-programming, python-decorators

I created a method `create_function` which returns another function with modified behaviour based on their arguments. My implementation works fine, but one thing bothers me: The returned function has this name `<function create_function.<locals>.new_func at ...>`. This makes error messages hard to interpret, because using `create_function` on different functions results in them having nearly identical names, when they raise an exception.

**create_function**

```
def create_function(func, arguments: dict):
    def new_func(x):
        return func(x, **arguments)

    return new_func


f = create_function(sum, {})
f() # Missing the parameter x should raise exception.

> TypeError: new_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I tried using a decorator but that did not work right.

```
def rename(new_name):
    def decorator(f):
        f.__name__ = new_name
        return f
    return decorator


def create_function(func, arguments: dict):
    @rename("Test")
    def new_func(x):
        return func(x, **arguments)

    return new_func


f = create_function(sum, {})
print(f.__name__)
f()

> Test
> TypeError: new_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

So is there a way to change the name of the returned function to something else than `new_func`?

**Edit**

So to clarify things a bit more, I want to show the name of the input function (in the upper example: `sum` instead of `new_func`) when raising an Error.
Using `wraps` from `functools` as suggested by Jiri Baum takes this one step closer to the goal:

**Using wraps**

```
from functools import wraps

def create_function(func, arguments: dict):
    @wraps(func)
    def new_func(x):
        return func(x, **arguments)
    
    return new_func


f = create_function(sum, {})
print(f.__name__) # Printing the name of the returned function
f()      # Raising an Type Error on purpose to show the Exception message

> <function sum at .> # This is what I wanted to show up!
> TypeError: new_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
 # No, here comes new_func again...
```

So is there any way to let the Exception say something like
`TypeError: sum() missing 1 required positional argument`???

Edit 2:
Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Use the `wraps` decorator from `contextlib`?

Comment: Also for the `rename` decorator you don't need the extra level...

Comment: @JiříBaum can you elaborate on both? I can't find `wraps decorator`in contextlib. How would you change the current decorator without extra level?

Comment: Sorry, `wraps` from `functools`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: For the extra level, I think I misread your code; the levels are fine they way they are. The argument that's missing is "x" - I'm not sure what you intend `x` to be, but you aren't supplying it when you call `f()`

Comment: @JiříBaum Thank you! Using `wraps` the name of the input function shows up when printing the returned function instance, but when raising an Exception there is still only: `TypeError: new_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

Comment: `new_func` is defined to take an argument, so you need to call `f` with one; for example:  `f(42)`

Comment: Yes, thats clear. In my edit I went into detail, I want that the ON PURPOSE called Error shows: `sum missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`!

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_function(func, arguments: dict):
    def demo(x):
        return func(x, **arguments)

    return demo
f = create_function #assigned function to variable.
f(sum,{}) # function call using varible f
```

Assign a function to the variable but without (). and then in that variable, if there is an argument then you have to pass that or just leave it var_name()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) but that doesn't solve my problem. I want to change the name of the returned function to something different than the defined name of the inner function (here `demo`), it makes debugging the returned function easier.

Comment: you mean, You want to change that def. If yes that's not possible because it is a reserved keyword in python.